# Get milliseconds independent from system date/time in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get the current(!) milliseconds for a custom timer-implmentation, but the milliseconds have to be independent from the actual system date/time:

When ever the system date/time is set to a new value (e.g. NTP-Update), the running(!) script should not be affected:

```
$t=microtime(true);

while ( ($t+100) < microtime(true) ) {
    ...
}
```

This loop is just waiting for 100 seconds. But what happens, when the user (or system) sets a new system date/time while the loop is running? Then the code would run into problems, because microtime() gives an absolute value - not a relative amount of milliseconds.

What I need is a (system-wide) function that tells me a system-date/time-independent value of milliseconds, e.g. milliseconds since boot-up.

Any idea?

Comment: I'd start with questioning whether this is really a problem that needs solving. How often does the system time change, how big a problem would this be, and isn't there maybe any other way you could approach this timer? Having said that, interesting problem.

Comment: This won't cause any problem.. Unless the system time changes **exactly** after `$t` and before the `while loop`.

Comment: Of course... But this is just an easy example - I've got several scripts running "forever" (CGI). The underlaying Linux is updating the system date/time by NTP each day (this is ok and should be done).

Comment: To be more precise: Let's say I've got a script that is called multiple times, but in random intervals (like a simple webpage). The script stores the time-value of it's last call and calculates the difference to now. The result is something like "last called 123.45 seconds before". But when system date/time is set to a new value (e.g. daylight-saving), the calculation is wrong because "now" isn't the expected value compared to the stored "old" value.